# How to display a view only once on application first run?

Tags: android

I want to develop an application that shows an authentication screen one time after installing it, and then other screens on subsequent runs. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `SharedPreference` to store a `firstboot` value, and check in the activity against that value. If the value is set, then the application has been launched before. Otherwise, you will display the activity and setthe `firstrun` flag in the `SharedPreference`.

For example, your your launched activity might look something like this,

```
public void onCreate(){
    boolean firstboot = getSharedPreference("BOOT_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstboot", true);

    if (firstboot){
        // 1) Launch the authentication activity

        // 2) Then save the state
        getSharedPreference("BOOT_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit()
            .putBoolean("firstboot", false)
            .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: thx i used it and it works but i didn't know how to pass to another activity when i launch the application for the second time

Comment: @emna declare else condition.

Comment: its not a stupid question, but im not sure if this is the best practice or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to do this. A `boolean` variable like as `isFirstTime` can see your work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SharedPreference` you can do that 
boolean flagmosque ;

```
public static void saveflagmosque(){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("mosque", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public boolean getflagmosque(){
        flagmosque = sharedPref.getBoolean("mosque", true);
        return flagmosque;
    }
```

In code

```
flagmosque = true ;
if(getflagmosque()){
your task that run only one time ;
}
```

Comment: Where to put this code ? in the activity that will be shown one tine ? or in the activity that display the next screen ?